# Xamarin Android - Java ran out of memory in VSTS but not on my machine

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-pipelines

When I build my Xamarin Android app on VSTS servers, I got the following error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of
>   $(JavaMaximumHeapSize)

So I added the following to my android csproj file:

```
<JavaMaximumHeapSize>1G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
```

However the error remained.

So:

1. Why would I have to increase `JavaMaximumHeapSize` in VSTS in the
   first place if I don't need to on my machine?
2. Why does the error
   remain?

Update

Here is the yml step with the build task:

```
  - task: XamarinAndroid@1
    displayName: 'Building Android'
    inputs:
        solutionFile: '**/*.sln'
        configuration: 'Release'
        buildToolOption: msbuild
```

Comment: Is your java environment set to X64 in the vsts build? In the Xamarin.Android build step at `JDK Options` your `JDK Architecture` should be set to x64.

Comment: I added the yml build step. Nothing about JDK options. I'll look into the task docs.

Comment: I don't really know about yml, but according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/xamarin-android?view=vsts it should be `jdkArchitectureOption: x64 # x86, x64 (default)` and therefore this would mean your environment is set to x64

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: You have to select a `JDK Version` first in order to set the `JDK Architecture`

Comment: Moreover, as you pointed out, x64 seems to be the default in yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is how I solved my issue.
My build task was using `solutionFile: '**/*.sln'` as an input.

And I realized that the build task was running all projects in my solution (even iOS while I clearly excluded it in Configuration Manager...). So somehow I reached the memomory limit (still haven't really understood how though).

So I changed the task input to `projectFile: 'MyApp.Android.csproj'` and then it built.